# karaf features-maven-plugin add-features-to-repo "Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency" despite it being right there

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to use the features-maven-plugin add-features-to-repo goal and I'm getting an odd error.

one feature looks like this.  Note guava 14.0.1 being listed as a bundle.

```
 <feature name='jersey-container-servlet-core' version='2.0'>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.0</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2.external/asm-all-repackaged/2.1.88</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api/2.1.88</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2.external/javax.inject/2.1.88</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:com.google.guava/guava/14.0.1</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.0</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.0</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils/2.1.88</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2.external/cglib/2.1.88</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator/2.1.88</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="55">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.0</bundle>
</feature>
```

when this plugin runs, I get these warnings:

```
[INFO]  Generating feature jersey-container-servlet-core from org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.0:compile
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency com.google.common.collect ([14.0.0,15.0.0)) (required by jersey-container-servlet-core)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency com.google.common.util.concurrent ([14.0.0,15.0.0)) (required by jersey-container-servlet-core)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency javax.servlet ([2.4.0,4.0.0)) (required by jersey-container-servlet-core)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency javax.servlet.http ([2.4.0,4.0.0)) (required by jersey-container-servlet-core)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency javax.ws.rs ([2.0.0,3.0.0)) (required by jersey-container-servlet-core)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency javax.ws.rs.core ([2.0.0,3.0.0)) (required by jersey-container-servlet-core)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency com.google.common.base ([14.0.0,15.0.0)) (required by jersey-common)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency com.google.common.collect ([14.0.0,15.0.0)) (required by jersey-common)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency com.google.common.net ([14.0.0,15.0.0)) (required by jersey-common)
[WARNING]   Unable to find suitable bundle for dependency com.google.common.primitives ([14.0.0,15.0.0)) (required by jersey-common)
```

for instance, all the "com.google.common" dependencies are in that guava bundle.  With a version that fits the range.

I do not understand what is going on.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing some required bundles, for example you're also missing a bundle which provides the servlet api. So you're most likely need to add a dependency to the pax-web feature which provides the servlet api bundle. To me it looks like the warning message could be the result of another "error" that's just hidden.